# SKProduct productIdentifier unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

I'm trying to implement in iPhone in app purchase in my app.

I have an IBAction on a button to buy a mini-game :

```
-(IBAction) buyGame:(id)sender {

    SKProduct *product = [[InAppGameIAHelper sharedHelper].products objectAtIndex:0];

    NSLog(@"Buying %@...", product.productIdentifier);

    [[InAppGameIAHelper sharedHelper] buyProductIdentifier:product.productIdentifier];
    self.hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.navigationController.view animated:YES];
    _hud.labelText = @"Buying...";

    [self performSelector:@selector(timeout:) withObject:nil afterDelay:60*5];
}
```

[InAppGameIAHelper sharedHelper] allows to load the items from the store, and to load the list of product.

[InAppGameIAHelper sharedHelper].products is a NSArray :

```
products (
    "com.me.myapp"
)
```

There when I am tapping the buy button my app getting crashed and getting the following error :

```
2013-03-04 20:24:50.314 isam[11922:c07] -[__NSCFConstantString productIdentifier]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x22ae30
2013-03-04 20:24:50.318 isam[11922:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString productIdentifier]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x22ae30'
```

Answer (score 0):

is the 
`SKProduct *product = [[InAppGameIAHelper sharedHelper].products objectAtIndex:0];` line actually returning you a `SKProduct`?

My guess is your code is crashing before it can print the `NSLog` because your method is returning somehow an `NSString`.

Comment: Yes you'r right, [[InAppGameIAHelper sharedHelper].products objectAtIndex:0] is a __NSCFConstantString. I don't know how to convert it in SKProduct.

Comment: mmm tricky. Did you do the code of your helper? Because basically you will have to modify that code

Comment: Hey and if you can select this answer as the right one it will help me a lot. Thanks.